# Realm db Case.INSENSITIVE not working

Tags: android, realm

I am trying to fetch all the values from the realm controller using search with case Insensitive but when there are two values "Animal , ant " in db and when I search an only ant is displayed . I have added Case.INSENSITIVE but its not working

```
return realm.where(Contact.class)
       .contains("name",searchString, Case.INSENSITIVE)
       .findAllSorted("name");
```

This is `Contact` class:

```
public class Contact extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String name;

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setUserId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }    
}
```

P.S using io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:1.1.0

Comment: what is the value of `searchString` here

Comment: "an" is the search string

Comment: Are there weird characters in the names, like áéóüöí?

Comment: No there are no words like that .. only english characters

Comment: can you post `Contact.java`

Comment: https://gist.github.com/sureshvaavel/28e694c5febee5a938312e9740a41bd8

Comment: If it is possible, please clone the realm-java repository at Github, write a unit test that reproduces the issue, and create a pull request. Speaking as a Realm developer, I will happy to fix the bug.

Comment: You should consider adding `@Index` on your `name` field, but there's technically no reason for this not to work.

Comment: @geisshirt I am new to android development I dont know how to do that ..

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Yeah I am still wondering the same  :/

Comment: You should send a basic example of reproducing this issue to `help[at]realm.io`

Comment: @SureshKumar You can find Realm's unit test of case insensitive queries at https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/realm/realm-library/src/androidTest/java/io/realm/RealmQueryTests.java#L830 - how does your code differ from it?

Comment: I tried to reproduce this but not success. https://gist.github.com/zaki50/8b8c2d8d35ea546635bdc2b2766a96e9 It seems to work as expected.

Comment: Are there any space/line break char in your search string?

Comment: It works now .. Added a trim function to the search string